# Why does this while loop in my class loop forever?

Tags: php, class, while-loop

I've incremented the loop and looked it over a good amount of times. The loop should just break when $change goes below 0, yet it loops forever until it exceeds the maximum time of 30 seconds. I'm a beginner, so I'd appreciate some help please.

```
<?php

class change{

private $cash = 0;
private $change = 0;
private $price = 0;
private $counter = 0;

public function setPrice($setPrice){
    $this->price = $setPrice;
 }

public function setCash($setCash){
    $this->cash = $setCash;
 }

public function getChange(){
    $this->change = ($this->cash - $this->price);
    while($this->change >= 0){
    $this->change - 50;
    $this->counter++;
  }
    return $this->counter;

  }
}


$newChange = new change;

$newChange->setCash(600);
$newChange->setPrice(200);

$newChange->getChange();

?>
```

Comment: even though you are subtracting 50 from `$this->change` you are not storing the result so `$this->change` will always stay the same for every loop iteration

Comment: What do you think `$this->change - 50;` does?

Comment: Thank you, are beginner questions usually looked down upon here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while($this->change >= 0){
    $this->change - 50;
    $this->counter++;
  }
```

You will need to actually set `$this->change` instead of just performing a subtraction. You can do `$this->change -= 50;`